# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:2

Tags: java, arrays, mapreduce, indexoutofboundsexception

Can someone please help me with this error?

Error is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at DCache.main(Dcache.java:197)
```

197th line would be **DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[2]), conf)**

Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

/**
* An example MapReduce program that uses the distributed cache.  It uses the NYSE_daily dataset, which has a schem of:
* exchange,stock_symbol,date,stock_price_open,stock_price_high,stock_price_low,stock_price_close,stock_volume,stock_price_adj_close
* and the NYSE_dividends data set, which has a schema of:
* exchange,stock_symbol,date,dividends
* It finds the adjusted closing price for each day that a stock reported a dividend.  The dividends data is placed in the distributed
* cache and then loaded into a lookup table so that the join can be done on the map side.
*/
public class DCache {

public static class Pair <T, U> {

    public T first;
    public U second;

    public Pair(T f, U s) {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (((this.first == null ? 1 : this.first.hashCode()) * 17)
                + (this.second == null ? 1 : this.second.hashCode()) * 19);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(! (other instanceof Pair)) {
            return false;
        }
        Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;
        boolean examinedFirst = false;
        boolean examinedSecond = false;
        if (this.first == null) {
            if (otherPair.first != null) {
                return false;
            }
            examinedFirst = true;
        }

        if (this.second == null) {
            if (otherPair.second != null) {
                return false;
            }
            examinedSecond = true;
        }

        if (!examinedFirst && !this.first.equals(otherPair.first)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!examinedSecond && !this.second.equals(otherPair.second)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private HashSet<Pair<String, String>> lookup = null;
    private Path[] localFiles;

    public void configure(JobConf job) {
        // Get the cached archives/files
        try {
            localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
            lookup = new HashSet<Pair<String, String>>();

            // Open the file as a local file
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(localFiles[0].toString());
            BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while ((line = d.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] toks = new String[4];
                toks = line.split(",", 4);
                // put the stock symbol
                lookup.add(new Pair<String, String>(toks[1], toks[2]));
            }
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<NullWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        // The first time we are invoked, open up our file from the distributed cache and populate our lookup table
        /*
        if (lookup == null) {
            lookup = new HashSet<Pair<String, String>>();

            // Open the file as a local file
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(localFiles[0].toString());
            BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while ((line = d.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] toks = new String[4];
                toks = line.split(",", 4);
                // put the stock symbol
                lookup.add(new Pair<String, String>(toks[1], toks[2]));
            }
            fr.close();
        }
        */

        // Convert the value from Text to a String so we can use the StringTokenizer on it.
        String line = value.toString();
        // Split the line into fields, using comma as the delimiter
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        // We only care about the 2nd, 3rd, and 9th fields (stock_symbol, date, and stock_price_adj_close)
        String stock_symbol = null;
        String date = null;
        String stock_price_adj_close = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9 && tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                stock_symbol = tokenizer.nextToken();
                break;

            case 2:
                date = tokenizer.nextToken();
                break;

            case 8:
                stock_price_adj_close = tokenizer.nextToken();
                break;

            default:
                tokenizer.nextToken();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (stock_symbol == null || date == null || stock_price_adj_close == null) {
            // This is a bad record, throw it out
            System.err.println("Warning, bad record!");
            return;
        } 

        if (stock_symbol.equals("stock_symbol")) {
            // NOP, throw out the schema line at the head of each file
            return;
        } 

        // Lookup the stock symbol and date in the lookup table
        if (lookup.contains(new Pair<String, String>(stock_symbol, date))) {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(stock_symbol);
            buf.append(',').append(date).append(',').append(stock_price_adj_close);
            output.collect(NullWritable.get(), new Text(buf.toString()));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JobConf conf = new JobConf(DCache.class);
  conf.setJobName("DistributedCache_Example");

  conf.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

  conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
  conf.setNumReduceTasks(0);

  conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
  conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

  DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[2]), conf);

  JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

Comment: Where is line 197 of Dcache.java?

Comment: edited my question accurately

Comment: You should (i) accept one of the answers if they helped you and (ii) ask a new question regarding your new problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, correction made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases.

```
lookup.add(new Pair<String, String>(toks[1], toks[2]));
```

First, toks length is equal to 2.  It means that the line you read does not have enough commas.

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[2]), conf);
```

Second, you are not passing enough arguments.
You need to pass three arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Following line seems to be returning just **1** element in array

```
 toks = line.split(",", 4);
```

Try inspecting `line` on above statement, and `toks` after this statement